# How i can adjust stopwatch to get the same values every time?

Tags: c#

How I can adjust stopwatch to get the same values every time?

For this code for example:

```
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    w.Start();
    test();
    w.Stop();

    w.Reset();

    Console.WriteLine(w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

I get different value each time.

Answer (score 4):

That's because of interruptions and how much resources your process/thread got allocated during execution. You can't do anything about it.

You should run your measurement multiple times and do some statistical analysis on the results: either average, median or e.g. 75th percentile

Comment: i used TimeSpan s = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime
to calculate time exactly when the the process is runing on cpu and i get good values some of them are identical and others have interval for multiple of 15.6001 and i don't understand why ?